# Google can't crawl my rewritten URLs

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, sitemap, googlebot, robots.txt

I tried to submit my `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` for hours now - changing directories and `.htacces` rules like a horse.

For some stupid reason Google can't crawl my pages and gives me warnings, that my urls in my `sitemap.xml` are blocked by the `robots.txt`, even if I allow Google to crawl my whole site with `Disallow:`. My `.htacces rules` working fine on my homepage.

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
# allow sitemap
Allow: /sitemap.xml

# allow article page
Allow: /blog/article/

# allow article 1
Allow: /blog/article/first-article

# sitemap url
Sitemap: http://www.my-page.de/sitemap.xml
```

**sitemap.xml**

```
...
<url>
  <loc>http://www.my-page.de</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.my-page.de/blog/article</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.my-page.de/blog/article/first-article</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
...
```

**.htaccess**

```
# ERROR DOCUMENTS
ErrorDocument 401 /includes/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /includes/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /includes/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 410 /includes/errors/404.php

# ACTIVATING REWRITEENGINE
RewriteEngine on

# TRANSLATE NON-WWW TO WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# TRANSLATE EVERY SUB_DOMAIN_PAGE TO DOMAIN_PAGE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mypage.de$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.my-page.de  [L,R]

# CLEAN URLS
# blog & article
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/article.?$ $article.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)first-article$ first-article.php
```

**root directory**

```
├─── ...
├─── blog
│    └─── first-article.php
├─── sitemap.xml
├─── robots.txt
├─── .htaccess
├─── article.php
├─── ...
```

**EDIT:** For some reason Google now managed to crawl through the URLs, listed in my sitemap. I changed absolutely nothing. Maybe the errors were caused due to the fact @closetnoc mentioned below (Google checks the robots.txt file periodically).

Comment: *Sitemap: http://www.my-page.de/sitemap.xml* is wrong. Remove it. Also, not sure what *Allow: /$* is supposed to do for you. Most people get into trouble by disallowing all first. It is usually far simpler and more successful to disallow specific sections only. BTW- your sitemap has nothing to do with this problem. It may be better to include your .htaccess to make sure there is not something wrong there.

Comment: Memorized. But as mentioned, even if I allow the crawlers to crawl every part of my page I get the same warnings/errors. The robots.txt shouldn't be the problem then, right?

Comment: You can test this quickly by blanking out your robots.txt file.

Comment: I deleted everything from the robots.txt and I get the same warnings again. So the problem is either my .htaccess or directorie I guess, is it maybe caused by the fact that a part of my re-written url's are also a directory in my root-folder?

Comment: You should use Google Search Console to test this. Google only checks the robots.txt file periodically, once per 24 hours generally, and otherwise may not be re-reading the file. Use the Search Console to test your robots.txt file and use Fetch as Google to ensure it can read your pages without using any cached robots.txt file. You may want to test a sample set of pages to ensure that it all works. BTW- your last entry in your robots.txt file is clearly not right. Whole URLs are not understood.

Comment: What "warnings" exactly are you getting? You had a `Disallow: /` directive initially - since removed - I presume that is not (and never has been) part of your robots.txt file? `$article.php` would seem to be an error in your .htaccess file.

Comment: I used "Fetch as Google" and the two pages I got warnings from were succesfully downloaded. It shows me, that I can send them to index, what does this mean?

Comment: @closetnoc "`Sitemap: http://www.my-page.de/sitemap.xml` is wrong"  - what's "wrong" with that?

Comment: @w3dk The URLs "http://www.my-page.de/blog/article" & "http://www.my-page.de/blog/article/first-article" get blocked by the robots.txt, even if it's empty or set to Disallow: without an /.

Comment: If you were able to successfully "Fetch as Google" and offered the option to submit to index then they aren't (currently) being blocked by `robots.txt`. Just to clarify, is your `robots.txt` in the root? ie. `/my-page.de/robots.txt`?

Comment: @w3dk Yes, of course. I added my root directory above.

Comment: @w3dk Nope. You are right! Gone cross-eyed. My bad!!

Comment: Is the missing hyphen in `mypage` here deliberate?

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mypage.de$   [NC]`

Comment: @MikeHudson It is. It's for redirecting from my subdomain, which is without the missing hypen.